# Built-in Kohana method to assist with developing an RSS feed

Tags: php, rss, kohana

I've discovered there is a helper to aid in the parsing of RSS feeds on the Kohana framework.

Is there one to help create one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.kohanaphp.com/helpers/feed#create

Answer (score 3):

Whip it up with the `create()` method of the `Feed` class in Kohana 3. You'll find the code of it at the following:

> system/classes/kohana/feed.php

You'll need to [define the channel information and its feed items as a minimum](http://www.kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php?id=working_with_atom_and_rss_feeds).

```
$info = array(
           'title' => 'Dark into the Narwhal',
           'pubDate' => date("D, d M Y H:i:s T"),
           'description' => 'Eating bacon, taking names and leaving fortunes',
           'link' => 'http://example.com/',
           'copyright' => 'The Narwhal Peon',
           'language' => 'en-us',
           'ttl' => '7200',
        );

$items = array(
           array(
               'title' => 'We journey with watermelon helmets',
               'link' => 'blog/journey-with-watermelon-helmets',
               'description' => 'Dawn breaks and the wind follows soon after. 
                                 We have found our supplies run low.',
           ),

            //-- and the other posts you want to include
         );
```

Then plug that data into the method to generate the XML:

```
$xml = Feed::create($info, $items);
```

Which will give you this when you `echo` it out or pass it to the relevant view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
  <title>Dark into the Narwhal</title>
  <pubDate>Fri, 21 Dec 2012 13:32:42 EST</pubDate>
  <description>Eating bacon, taking names and leaving fortunes</description>
  <link>http://example.com/</link>
  <copyright>The Narwhal Peon</copyright>
  <language>en-us</language>
  <ttl>7200</ttl>
  <generator>KohanaPHP</generator>
  <item>
    <title>We journey with watermelon helmets</title>
    <link>http://example.com/blog/journey-with-watermelon-helmets</link>
    <description>Dawn breaks and the wind follows soon after. 
                 We have found our supplies run low.</description>
  </item>

  <!-- the other posts will be here -->

  </channel>
</rss>
```